# inputing hex and reading hex with C++

Tags: c++, input, hex

I'm trying to read and write hex but I'm having trouble inputting hex and reading hex back as hex not ascii. Whats getting me is printing the addresses, and values correctly I'm not quite sure I'm doing it right. any hints as to what I'm doing wrong? ok its working so far now just to fix read to print the actual address instead of entered address +1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char ** argv) {
    if(argc <= 1) {
        cout<<"Enter a file name please";
        exit(0);
    } else {
       fstream in;
       in.open(argv[1],fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
       string input;
       unsigned int v;
       unsigned int print;
       unsigned int g;
       int iter;
         for(iter = 0; input!="save";){
            cout<<"Hex Edit("<<argv[1]<<"): ";
            cin>>input;
            if(input == "read"){
               cout<<"Enter Offset: ";
               cin>>hex>>v;
               in.seekg(v);
               print=in.get();
               g=in.tellg();
               cout<<"Value at offset("<<hex<<g<<"): "<<hex<<print;
               cout<<endl;
           }
           if(input == "write"){
              cout<<"Enter Offset: ";
              cin>>hex>>v;
              in.seekp(v);
              cout<<"Enter Value: ";
              cin>>hex>>v;
              in.put(v);
            }
            } else if(input == "save") {
                in.close();
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like both C and C++ so it doesn't matter I'm an end point kinda guy :D

Comment: hex input is very much UB in both C and C++ (when user gives you garbage). so the way to do that is to read to a buffer, and convert.

Comment: Thanks Snyex for the indentation I didn't think that you could use more than 4 spaces?

Comment: it skips input value for some reason??? pretty sure its not coded that way whats going on ? do i need to flush ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be intending to read and write one character at a time - cin and cout are both capable of working with integral values and this would be ideal here. Keep in mind that hexadecimal strings do represent numbers! Streams are capable of interpreting them as such. Simply changing the variables v and print to type int will allow you to read in an entire hexadecimal value at once.

For an example:

```
int value;
cin >> hex >> value;
cout << hex << value;
```

Comment: so I need to apply hex to cin as well then ? whats am I doing thats causing it to skip over "Enter value:" ?

Comment: Fixed it I don't know if it was me calling scanf that caused it but its fixed and it prints just fine cept when I print the address in the read(if statement) it reads 0x16 as 0x17 or rather a +1 ?

Comment: @Aquertu I'd need to see that section of your new code to see exactly what's going on. scanf/printf should not be mixed with cin/cout - they are two very different ways of handling input. A good idea would be to try to narrow down the non-working code to the simplest program possible with the issue, so we can ignore the rest of the program that is unrelated to the issue.

Comment: the key change to that section of code was cout<<"Value at offset("<<hex<<g<<"): "<<hex<<print; where G is = to in.tellg()

Comment: Edit: Looking back at this comment it was not as clear as it could be. `in.seekg(v);` moves the file pointer to `v`. `in.get();` will then read from that address, but also move the file pointer forward, so that a subsequent call to `in.get();` will not read the exact same location. because of this, `in.tellg()` will return `v+1` - as the file pointer is no longer `v` but has advanced. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the help man :D didn't know that hex operated on cin too i just did g-1 to fix the issue alls working now :)